# AlarmManager setRepeating not working with daily interval

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I encountered an issue while trying to setup a daily notification.

I used `AlarmManager` to setup an alarm at 6:00pm everyday

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
if (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 18) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}

calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000,
    pendingIntent);
```

But I don't know why the first alarm is fired at exact 18:00, but the next alarm fires at random time. Sometime 19:30, sometime 20:06. I just don't understand what I'm wrong here.

I tried both `INTERVAL_DAY` or `24*60*60*1000` - nothing worked. 
But it worked fine with interval of 1 minute, 5 minutes, 10 minutes, 1h etc.

AlarmReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
        context.startService(service1);
        System.out.println("alarm");
    }
}
```

MyAlarmService:

```
public class MyAlarmService extends Service {
     private NotificationManager mManager;

     @Override
     public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
     }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
       super.onCreate();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
       super.onStart(intent, startId);

       mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);

       Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Test notification", System.currentTimeMillis());

       intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

       PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
       notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
       notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(), "Test", "Test a notification", pendingNotificationIntent);

       mManager.notify(0, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you running the code on? Is it an Android 4.4 device or emulator? Or is it something else? Also, what is the `PendingIntent` that you are using?

Comment: I added my pendintIntent Code, it just an simple Receiver to show a notification when alarm is fired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. `setRepeating()` is inexact on Android 4.4+ with an `android:targetSdkVersion` of 19 or higher.
2. You are not using `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, my `WakefulIntentService`, or your own `WakeLock`, and so the device can fall back asleep between the time the alarm is triggered any by the time your service completes its work.

In this case, you can solve #2 easier by just moving the code from `onStart()` (which, BTW, has been deprecated for ~5 years) into `onReceive()` and getting rid of the service entirely. You only need a service here if you are doing disk I/O or network I/O; raising a `Notification` should be cheap.

Comment: thankyou, i will try and give a feedback soon, i'm new in android and this is code from local notification sample

Comment: How inexact setRepeating() is? I mean, if I want it to be called like once every ~5 mins, can I be sure it'll be called in 5 to say 8 minutes or it might be even 20 minutes?

Comment: @AlexBerdnikov: "How inexact setRepeating() is?" -- that is not documented, unfortunately. :-(